# Loading jquery depending on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and struggling with this basic problem - I want to load jQuery only if the window size is below a certain threshold (i.e., the mobile version doesn't require it). For the desktop version, jQuery must load in the `<head>` and not the `<body>`, as the content above the fold requires it.

I've tested the loop, and I'm getting the screen width printed on the page, but jQuery isn't loading. I'm sure it's a basic syntax problem but I just can't see it! Any help would be most appreciated. :)

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function loadjsfile(filename){
         var fileref=document.createElement('script');
         fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
         fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
         }

        var w=window.innerWidth
        || document.documentElement.clientWidth
        || document.body.clientWidth;
            if (w > 899){
                document.write("screen Width: " + w);
                loadjsfile("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js");
                }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you've created the `fileref` variable that contains your script tag object but you never add it to the DOM, thus it never loads.

```
function loadjsfile(filename){
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);

    //add this line
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

Comment: Also, that function is missing semicolon everywhere.

Comment: whoops - have put the semicolons in!

Comment: If you throw an `alert()` or `console.log()` call in that function does it get called?

Comment: yeah, if I put an alert within loadjsfile it pops up before the page loads

Comment: can you see if it is actually loading/adding that tag into the head when you view the console DOM tree?  I'm wondering if it is loading fine, but the plugin (or whatever requires jQuery) is actually attempting to load before you're inclusion of jQuery? Is this site public by any chance?

Comment: The site is luke-davies.com ... lightbox-2.6.min.js and svg_inject_flat_icons_filled.js require jquery and are complaining that it's not loaded - but the script occurs before they're called :S

Comment: I think when you add a script tag with JS it's always loaded asynchronously, that means though this code occurs before your plugins, jQuery is probably not loaded by the time the plugins are loaded. Also, if you are trying to toggle the plugins by either loading jQuery or not, there are probably better ways.

Comment: hi christian, i'm not trying to toggle the plugins based on a jQuery load - i'm trying to load jQuery based on the window size as for the mobile version, i don't call any elements that require it